# Can you open multiple files at once in Pages

Tags: macos, pages

I am running high sierra on my iMac. I would like to do some copying and pasting from one document to another.  I use Pages to create and edit my documents. Is there a way to open 2 or more documents at once in Pages?  Or is there a way to do what I'd like in a single version of Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm… am I missing something here?

You just open as many documents as you like and reposition the windows next to each other, like so:

[image: Pages 4 document quadrants]

Comment: when i open the 2nd doc the first one closes!

Comment: ah geez, it doesn't close. My bad. thank you.  i made a dumb mistake.